# how to insert multiple text values to a column in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following texts:

```
OR (((Sales.customer)=""))
OR (((Sales.customer)=""))
OR (((Sales.customer)=""))
OR (((Sales.customer)=""))
OR (((Sales.customer)=""))
OR (((Sales.customer)=""))
```

Where I need to insert a list of different values in between "". Alt + C can only allow single value insert... So how do I insert multiple values in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to dynamically replace those quotes with values using notepad ++.

I can think of a few ways you can do this with code.

I create some js code that will go through an array and print out the values, here: https://jsfiddle.net/cumqd69r/

or here is some python that will do the same:

```
#python
line = 'OR (((Sales.customer)="%s"))'
for value in ('value1', 'value2', 'valueN'):
    print line % value
```